# Is Ansible failing to activate the 'become' user?

Tags: ansible, root, dhcp

I have a playbook role which reads from a template (locally) and write it into an output configuration file (also locally).

The "hosts" entry is used as a loop mechanism so that it can generate the IP DHCP information for all three switches. The playbook IS NOT meant to connect to those switches.

The /root/dhcp has already been created.

The playbook that calls this role:

```
- name: Create ISC DHCP entry
  hosts: switch1, switch2, switch3
  connection: local
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  tags:
    - dhcp_entry
  roles:
   - dhcp_entry
```

The role is shown below:

```
-   name: Template to local configuration file
    template:
        src: dhcp_entry.j2
        dest: "/root/dhcp/dhcpd.con/{{inventory_hostname}}.cfg"
```

This is how I execute the role:

```
ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml --tags dhcp_entry -K
BECOME password:
```

My problem is:

1. If I login to the Ansible controller (a Fedora 36) as root and run this play, it just works.
2. If I run this play as me (a local user) by calling the following command, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [switch1]: FAILED! => {

    "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/root/dhcp/dhcpd.con/switch1.cfg): Permission denied"

}
```

Could it be that "become" not working properly?

This is the output of -vvvv:

```
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
Loading collection ansible.netcommon from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon
redirecting (type: terminal) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
Loading collection cisco.ios from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/cisco/ios
redirecting (type: cliconf) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
<192.168.101.37> attempting to start connection
<192.168.101.37> using connection plugin ansible.netcommon.network_cli
Found ansible-connection at path /usr/bin/ansible-connection
<192.168.101.37> local domain socket does not exist, starting it
<192.168.101.37> control socket path is /home/karl/.ansible/pc/335359206a
<192.168.101.37> redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
<192.168.101.37> Loading collection ansible.netcommon from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/netcommon
<192.168.101.37> redirecting (type: terminal) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
<192.168.101.37> Loading collection cisco.ios from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/cisco/ios
<192.168.101.37> redirecting (type: cliconf) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
<192.168.101.37> local domain socket listeners started successfully
<192.168.101.37> loaded cliconf plugin ansible_collections.cisco.ios.plugins.cliconf.ios from path /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/cisco/ios/plugins/cliconf/ios.py for network_os ios
<192.168.101.37> ssh type is set to paramiko
<192.168.101.37> 
<192.168.101.37> local domain socket path is /home/karl/.ansible/pc/335359206a
<192.168.101.37> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: karl
<192.168.101.37> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422="` echo /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422 `" ) && sleep 0'

Using module file /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/modules/stat.py

<192.168.101.37> PUT /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/tmp22s70vr9 TO /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422/AnsiballZ_stat.py

<192.168.101.37> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422/ /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422/AnsiballZ_stat.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.101.37> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422/AnsiballZ_stat.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.101.37> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/karl/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-37861a01d_aba/ansible-tmp-1653985277.510138-37870-122038318639422/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [ipga.ph]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/root/dhcp/switch1.cfg): Permission denied"

}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

ipga.ph                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Thank you.

Comment: your local user belongs to group sudoer?

Comment: Yes. It belongs to the "wheel" group.

Comment: are you sure on all hosts? check the contents of wheel group of each host

Comment: I'm only using the "hosts: switch1, switch2, switch3" for iteration. I'm not trying to communicate with those hosts.

So the role iterate through these hosts one by one, then creates a IP DHCP information for each host. Everything happens locally. The controller is not supposed to communicate outside.

Comment: do a -vvvvv to see the user used to connect

Comment: I just added the -vvvv. I'm not sure why the controller is using the ios module (Cisco IOS) even though the connection is set to be local.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ansible you have?,

try with this,

```
 become: true
 become_method: su
 become_user: nobody
 become_flags: '-s /bin/sh'
```

Comment: Hello,

[karl@fedora]$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.5]


I tried adding those "become" lines into the playbook but it has returned the same output unfortunately.